# IntelliJ can't find Spring bean from Kotlin object

Tags: spring, intellij-idea, kotlin

I have a Spring Boot 2 + Kotlin application opened with IntelliJ 2019.1.

In this application I annotate some Kotlin objects with `@Component`. Example:

```
@Component
object MyObject: MyInterface {
    // code
}
```

I have many different implementation of `MyInterface` (all with Kotlin objects) and I want to inject all of them in a list in another bean. Example:

```
@Component
class MyComponent @Autowired constructor(private val objects: List<MyInterface>) {
    // code
}
```

The code runs correctly (the beans are inject in the list `objects`) but IntelliJ shows an error saying:

> Could not autowire. No beans of '? extends MyInterface' or 'List<? extends MyInterface>' types found.

If I change 'object' to 'class' at 'MyObject', the error disappears.

My questions are:

- Is it a problem with IntelliJ?
- Is it not recommended to annotate Kotlin objects with `@Component`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a little bit strange to use Kotlin objects as `@Component`-s, because if your class knows that it will be used inside Spring-container you'll get more flexibility if you delegate to Spring the decision should this class be a singleton or not and all the other lifecycle management.

But practically I don't see any reason why it could be "not recommended" if you know what you are doing, and aware of probably bugs if your `object` become stateful.

So I think IDEA should support your case, and I've filled up a ticket [IDEA-211826](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-211826)

Comment: Thanks @Николай! I'll follow the ticket you filled.

Answer (score 2):

For information, as a possible workaround while the [ticket](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-211826) created by Николай in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55891936/7952453) is not treated, I'm ignoring the error/warning only where I need with `@Suppress("SpringJavaInjectionPointsAutowiringInspection")`. Example:

```
@Suppress("SpringJavaInjectionPointsAutowiringInspection")
@Autowired
private lateinit var kotlinObjectBeans: List<MyInterface>
```

I hope it can help others that don't want to disable this check elsewhere.

Comment: Still no solution found for this?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend **not to use** kotlin objects with `@Component` or any other bean annotation.

There are two aspects and heaving a mix of them leads to lots of problems:

1. It might be several `ApplicationContext` instances in your application.
2. Kotlin object is related to a specific `ClassLoader`